# UIViewController, UIView and View hierarchy in ios4 SDK / iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Can someone exlain the view hierarchy in iphone/ipad development?

I want to know what is the "root" element I need to display a textBox on the screen.

I also would like to know how I can populate a UITableViewController subclass without having to use a NIB.

Is the minimum components is:

```
Window
    UiViewController  
          UIView
              UITextBox
```

or

```
Window  
   UIView
      UITextBox
```

@  Richard J. Ross III

Where do I put myTableView??

```
Window  
   myTableView
```

What type is myTableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum components is that, but it is recommended to use the `UIViewController`, as it allows you to do some cool stuff with `UITableViews`, `UITabBars`, etc. UITableViewController subclass without nib:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyController : UITableViewController
// custom methods here
@end

@implementation MyController

–(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // initializes the table with 10 rows
    return 10;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSLog(@"the user selected row: %@", indexPath);
}

@end
```

Then, to use that custom controller:

```
MyController *control = [[MyController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
// now hook it up!
myTableView.dataSource = control;
myTableView.delegate = control;
[control release];
```

Sorry for my syntax errors, I wrote this without an IDE (e.g. straight on stackoverflow).

Comment: Where do I place myTableView? Window UIViewController myTableView??

--sorry I dont know how to format the comments

Comment: myTableView is a UITableView Created from a .nib, with an outlet to your code

Comment: What if I dont want to use a nib?  Do I need to add a UIViewController then the UITableView

Comment: Creating tableviews without a nibs is a pain in the butt. I would not attempt such a thing, as there are so many rules to conform to, just use the simplicity of the nib, after all, thats what It is there for :)

Answer (score 1):

The first guess is correct.  A UIViewController manages a view property, which is a UIView.  The controller is in charge of taking care of things when certain events occur.  If the user rotates his device, the viewController is the object that hears about it.  If you have coded for this event, the viewController will pass an instruction to the UIView to rotate.  There is special code in the viewController that can decide what to do when the view appears, disappears, loads, unloads, etc.

UITableViewController manages a tableView.  In the default XCode setup, the Table View DataSource and Delegate is the UITableViewController subclass.  The delegate manages what happens when a user interacts with the table, by selecting rows, scrolling, etc.  The data source houses information that populates the rows in the table, headers and footers.

If you want to show a textbox in a tableViewCell, you'll need a UITableView object, and a UITextField.  You have to make the dataSource give the table a UITextField as a row, and add it to the UITableViewCell's view, which is called contentView.